# I want a validation one of two values shoud be required

Tags: node.js

```
PostAnswer(obj){
    const schema = Joi.object({
        questionguid: Joi.string().required(),
        answertext: Joi.string().required(),
        answerurl:  Joi.string().allow(null, ""),
        transcriptiontext: Joi.string().allow(null,""),
        threadguid: Joi.string().required()
    })
    return schema.validate(obj)
}
```

I am using this code to validate but I need validation like answertext or answerurl one of them should be required

Comment: Can you explain the expected behavior more in detail? should at least one of them have value? Can not both of them have value at the same time?

Comment: Does `.or('answertext', 'answerurl')` solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xor` which provides an exclusive relationship between a set of keys where one of them is required but not at the same time.

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    questionguid: Joi.string().required(),
    answertext: Joi.string().allow(null, ""),
    answerurl:  Joi.string().allow(null, ""),
    transcriptiontext: Joi.string().allow(null,""),
    threadguid: Joi.string().required()
}).xor('answertext', 'answerurl')
```

Comment: It's not working when I am giving both values null it's giving this validation error
""answertext" is not allowed to be empty"
And when I am giving first value then this error
""value" contains a conflict between exclusive peers [answertext, answerurl]"

Comment: You can only provide one value.

Comment: It's not working when I am giving both values null it's giving this validation error
""answertext" is not allowed to be empty"
And when I am giving first value then this error
""value" contains a conflict between exclusive peers [answertext, answerurl]"

Comment: And when giving second value then it's making first one required

Comment: You have to allow `answertext` to accept `null` and empty. See the updated answer.

Comment: Now in every case it's givng this error
""value" contains a conflict between exclusive peers [answertext, answerurl]"

Comment: Can you explain your expected behavior? I thought you wanted either `answertext` and `answerurl` and not both.

Comment: Yes I want anyone of these two